# @Html.EditorFor sends wrong value to the controller

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, editorformodel

I created `@Html.EditorFor` for `ICollection` list which looks like this.

```
 public virtual ICollection<DescriptionParameters> DescriptionParameters { get; set; }
```

Class DescriptionParameters shown below.

```
public partial class DescriptionParameters
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required (ErrorMessage = "Please enter description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter description parameter")]
        public string DescriptionParameter { get; set; }
        public int Product_Id { get; set; }

        public virtual Product ProductSet { get; set; }
    }
```

I created    `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.DescriptionParameters,new {Id="DescriptEditor" })`     inside Html form .
For this Editor i created EditorForTemplate.

```
@model OnlineShop.Models.DescriptionParameters
<script src="~/Scripts/DiscriptionParameters.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<table>
    <tr>  
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Description, new { Id="DescriptionField",Class = "EnterDescriptionInfoField" })

        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DescriptionParameter, new { Id = "DescriptionParamField", Class = "EnterDescriptionParameterInfoField" })

        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="AddDescription" type="button" value="+" 
                   style="width:20px;height:20px" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="RemoveDescription" type="button" value="-"
                    style="width:20px;height:20px;text-align:center" />
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Description)
        </td>
        <td style="padding-left:10px">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.DescriptionParameter)
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to make next behavior for my application(see screenshot):When it is pressed second "-" button,it should  deletes second element in the list,instead of ,it always deletes first element in `ICollection` list in spite of my choice.
[image: EditorFor in the view]

For this reason i use `DiscriptionParameters` script.Which looks like this.

```
$('.RemoveDescription').click(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/AddProductsDialog/RemoveDescriptionParameter',
        context: this,
        type: 'GET',
        data: $('#AddProdForm').serialize() + "&description="
            + $('.EnterDescriptionInfoField').val() + "&descriptionParametr="
            + $('.EnterDescriptionParameterInfoField').val(),
        success: function (product) {
            $('#ProgressShow').empty()
            $('#AddProdForm').replaceWith(product)
        }
    })
})
```

Which sends data to the RemoveDescriptionParameter action method.

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult RemoveDescriptionParameter(Product product,string description,
            string descriptionParameter)
        {
            if(description=="")
            {
                description = null;
            }
            if (descriptionParametr == "")
            {
                description = null;
            }
            if (product.DescriptionParameters.Count > 1)
            {
                product.DescriptionParameters.Remove(
                    product.DescriptionParameters.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Description==description 
                    && x.DescriptionParameter==descriptionParametr));
            }
            GoodsContainer1 goods = new GoodsContainer1();
            ViewData["Categories"] = goods.CategorySet;
            ViewData["SubCategories"] = goods.SubCategorySet;
            return PartialView("~/Views/AddProductsDialog/AddProducts.cshtml", product);
        }
```

In RemoveDescriptionParameter method for `description` and
 `descriptionParameter` parameters,i get values of first element in list,instead of chosed list element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this line in your code.

> "&description=" + $('.EnterDescriptionInfoField').val()

Your jQuery selector is the css class. Your razor code will more than one input fields  with this css class (*Just check the view source of your page and you will see it*) when your `DescriptionParameters` contains more than one item.

jQuery `val()` method returns you **the value of the first element in the set of matched elements**. That means, If you had 3 items in your `DescriptionParameters` property, your razor code create 3 table and you will have three inputs with css class name `EnterDescriptionInfoField`. `$('.EnterDescriptionInfoField')` will give you an array of 3 inputs matching the jQuery selector and `val()` will return the value of first item in the array !

You should be using relative jQuery selector(s). You may use the jQuery `closest` method to get the current table row and use find method to get the input with the specific css class.

This should work.

```
$(function(){

  $('.RemoveDescription').click(function() {

     $.ajax({
             url: '/AddProductsDialog/RemoveDescriptionParameter',
             context: this,
             type: 'GET',
             data: $('#AddProdForm').serialize() +
             "&description=" +
                            $(this).closest("tr").find('.EnterDescriptionInfoField').val() +
             "&descriptionParametr=" +
                    $(this).closest("tr").find('.EnterDescriptionParameterInfoField').val(),
             success: function(product) {
                //do something with the response
             }
     });

  });

});
```